# How to assign a random color in an array?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

Hey I have an array with different colors and I want that every chip that is created has a random color of this array. I tried to put all color strings in the array and look if the chips are created with the colors of the array after another. But that didnt worked.
How can I do that?

HTML

```
<ion-chip [color]="color" class="chip" #chip *ngFor="let tag of tagName">
```

TS

```
 public color: string [] = ["ok", "nice","awesome","danger","white"]
```

tagName

```
export class Tag {
  tag: string;
  constructor(values: Object = {}) {
    Object.assign(this, values);
  }
```

...

```
  tagName: Tag[] = [];
```

...

```
  add(): void {
      let id = this.tagName.length + 1;
      this.tagName.push(new Tag({ tag: "tag" + id }, ));
    }

    remove(tag: Tag) {
      let id = this.tagName.indexOf(tag);
      this.tagName.splice(id, 1);
    }
```

Comment: When you say that didn't work, what went wrong?

Comment: When I add more than one element to the array it just has the default color = grey. So the array only works with one string.

Comment: Just compare the length of the chips with the length of the color array to make sure they're different from one chip to the next.

Answer (score 1):

```
getRandomColor() {
var color = Math.floor(0x1000000 * Math.random()).toString(16);
return '#' + ('000000' + color).slice(-6);
}
```

ScreenShot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is generate a random index, from 0 to the length of your array:

```
getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}
```

Then, set the color like so:

```
[color]="color[getRandomInt(color.length)]"
```

Comment: Oh thx:) And what do I have to add to the array? I dont really get the thing with the color length.

Comment: You can use the color array you already have in your question.

Comment: Because atm I get this error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenChecked

Comment: Okay, can you add the your question what the tagName JSON looks like?

Comment: Now its in the question

Comment: before the error message comes the chips changes very fast the color that are in the array. if that helps